# Extract HLS encryption key?

Tags: encryption, stream, http-live-streaming, capture

I've managed to download the hls from a website I've legally subscired to and am trying to save the videos for offline playback on my computer because the buffering is way too slow and doesn't allow me to shuffle through content quickly.

Is there a way to decrypt the downloaded hls stream file by feeding it with the online feed of the website or can it be read somewhere in the site's code itself?

Is there another way to capture the videos? By maybe tapping the buffer feed?

Although I haven't found an app yet that can do this. I usually used video download helper but that doesn't work anymore with encrypted hls streams.

Comment: It depends. If it’s basic clear key, you can just watch the network traffic. If it’s ful DRM, then there is nothing you can do.

Comment: How am I able to figure it out? Can you maybe take a look at it?

Comment: Look at the playlist.